# matlab c++ engine API: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, matlab, segmentation-fault, abi

I built an c++ API engine using a minimal example as shown here
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/test-your-build-environment.html

which works fine.

My real exexutable is however linked against another external library. If I place any symbol (an object,...) of this library in my code, I run in a segmentation fault; I think there is an issue with ABI incompatible versions of the same external library linked into the executable.
In particular, the call to startMATLAB() results in a segmentation fault. To debug this, I produced a backtrace with gdb:

As you can see, at the top of the stacktrace is the libmwmvm.so library.
What is this library used for and does anyone has an idea how to debug those kind of problems further?

```
Starting program: /step-1
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffbddff640 (LWP 3220190)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbd5fe640 (LWP 3220191)]
Thread 3 "step-1" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffbd5fe640 (LWP 3220191)]
0x00007fffc60cab83 in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffc60cab83 in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
#1  0x00007fffd7099f68 in __pthread_once_slow (once_control=0x5555558569a0, init_routine=0x7fffd74dadb0 <__once_proxy>) at ./nptl/pthread_once.c:116
#2  0x00007fffc60ca6cd in mvm::detail::DefaultSession::getTransportSession() const () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
#3  0x00007fffc60bc8e1 in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
#4  0x00007fffc60f9cbd in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
#5  0x00007fffc60fa152 in mvm::MatlabFactory::createFactory(mwboost::shared_ptr<mvm::Session> const&, mvm::FactoryOptions const&, mvm::ShutdownPolicy, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, fl::filesystem::basic_path<char, char16_t, fl::filesystem::detail::path_traits<char, char16_t> >, std::shared_ptr<mvm::Credentials>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, bool, unsigned long, std::optional<mwboost::chrono::duration<long, mwboost::ratio<1l, 1l> > >, bool) ()
from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so
#6  0x00007fffc6408a54 in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwengine_api.so
#7  0x00007fffc641ac1c in std::_Function_handler<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> (), std::__future_base::_Task_setter<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result<unsigned long long>, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter>, std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<unsigned long long (*)(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > >), std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > > > >, unsigned long long> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwengine_api.so
#8  0x00005555555f781a in std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>::operator()() const (this=0x7fffbd5ef780) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_function.h:591
#9  0x00005555555efb8e in std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_do_set(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*) (this=0x7fffb8000b80, __f=0x7fffbd5ef780, 
__did_set=0x7fffbd5ef757) at /usr/include/c++/12/future:572
#10 0x00007fffd7099f68 in __pthread_once_slow (once_control=0x7fffb8000b98, init_routine=0x7fffd74dadb0 <__once_proxy>) at ./nptl/pthread_once.c:116
#11 0x00007fffc641d3fc in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<unsigned long long (*)(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > >), std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > > > >, unsigned long long>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<unsigned long long (*)(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > >), std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > > > >&&)::{lambda()#1}> > >::_M_run() ()
from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwengine_api.so
#12 0x00007fffd74dc2b3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#13 0x00007fffd7094b43 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442
#14 0x00007fffd7126a00 in clone3 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:81
```

Comment: I think that is the MATLAB Virtual Machine. It probably links against some library that your application also links against, but you are using a different version of the library. Use `ldd` to see which (dynamic) libraries are linked by `libmwmvm.so`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo libmwmvm.so links against libtbb.so.2 (thread building blocks library), and my executable does it as well, however, my executable uses a different version of tbb. Do you know how I can force matlab to link against the version that my executable links against?

Comment: You will need to link against the version that MATLAB links against -- you can rebuild your program with different versions of libraries, but you cannot rebuild MATLAB. In short, you are trying to get MATLAB to link to your version of TBB, but it's not compatible, and so it crashes.

Comment: Why is this crash not catched by gdb?

Comment: What do you mean it's not caught by gdb? You show a gdb backtrace.

Comment: I mean why the backtrace is not more descriptive regarding the source of the segfault? The top of the backtrace just says $0x00007fffc60cab83 in ?? () from /opt/MATLAB/R2023a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so$ which is not really helpful in my opinion.

Comment: The MATLAB library has no debug information. If it’s not a public function, there is no name in the name table to show you.

Comment: Say the above segfault is not caused by the different tbb versions, what else would you do to debug further? The tbb library is the only library that my executable and matlab share according to ldd.

Comment: You should figure out which version of TBB is used by MATLAB, then fetch the exact same version from the repository, build it, and link against that version -- ignore whatever version you have installed. I presume there's an libtbb.so file in the MATLAB distribution. I hope it has some versioning information embedded.

Comment: For example, when I do `strings libtbb.dylib` (on my Mac, this works the same on Linux but with .so extension for the library file) I see strings such as "oneTBB: SPECIFICATION VERSION", "oneTBB: VERSION", "2021.9", "oneTBB: INTERFACE VERSION", "12090". I'm guessing that is the information you'd need to find the right version in its repository.

Comment: But you could also try linking against the static version of the library (.a instead of .so), often that avoids this type of problem.

Comment: I did <<find matlabroot -iname libtbb*>> which returned libtbb.so.2 and libtbbmalloc.so.2 . <<strings libtbb.so.2 contained "TBB: VERSION    2020.0". The version my executable links against to is 2020.3. So you would suggest me to re-compile my library and link the executable against TBB 2020.3 ?

Comment: No, you should recompile your program to use the 2020.0 version that MATLAB is using. That way you both use the same version.

Comment: Yes, typo...  I will give it a try and hope that I can do that with spack (package manager).

Comment: Why do you think linking against the static version of tbb would be a workaround?

Comment: I've used static linking in the past to get around issues like this. I don't know if it'll work with TBB as well, but it certainly worked with e.g. the Zlib library, where MATLAB has one version loaded, and my MEX-file was using a newer version. Having the MEX-file statically linked to Zlib in that case avoided the conflicts.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I still get the same segfault after linking me exexutable against intel-tbb 2020.0. Any idea what else I could try to fix the issue?